# Adding Multiple Textfiled values has to retrieve in one textfield

Tags: drupal, text, field, drupal-webform

I have a kind form which is having some kind of calculation (sum). 
For example, I have 5 textfields. I would like the total sum of 1+2+3+4 into 5th textfiled.
I'm using drupal webforms for designing my form
Can you please suggest how to validate and how to retrieve the values from textfield in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the ids generated for each textfield by webform and have a javascript to add the values of how many ever text boxes you want. Attach a listener to the first four text fields using jquery such that it fires a function on occurance of onchange event.

Comment: Thank you vivek. But i'm new to drupal and can you pls elaborate where to write/place js or jquery in drupal. If possible can you refer some code or any reference with example. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.  It will allow you to make calculations on field values and insert that new value into another field.

From the project page:

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of CCK fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

Comment: Hi Laxman, Thank you for reference. I added the Computed Field module to my site. But, I'm unable to configure/customize and i'm unable to solve my problem explained. Tobe frank i'm new to drupal. Can you please explain and give rough solution to my question please.

Comment: Here are a _bunch_ of examples of ways to use Computed Fields: [Computed Field Examples](http://drupal.org/node/126522) Look through those and you should be able to work through it.  If you aren't familiar with PHP, you may have to learn that first

Comment: still unable to process laxman. I was unable to solve my issue with that. Can you have anymore suggestions for my issue... please